# Question about the symlink of the ln command

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link

Can anybody give me an example why should we use the symlink kind of the "ln" command between files? I know that when you create symlink file, that file size is very small and it redirect to the main file.

The problem is when I created the symlink from a specific file (text file) from another directory, but I can't cat, less or any kind of print and view that file. Pls help me understand more about this type.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you post the precise command(s) you typed. I suspect a path error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let say you have a file named `/home/george/Images/ubuntu.jpg` and you want it to be available too in the `/var/tmp` directory, you can run:

```
ln -s /home/george/Images/ubuntu.jpg /var/tmp
```

Then, you can equally view the file using the `/var/tmp/ubuntu.jpg` path.

Beware not to miss to provide a correct relative or absolute path for the first parameter passed to the link command. This path is relative to the directory where the symbolic link resides. This is a common source of mistakes, like Nitin reply demonstrates.

Comment: That's great. Now I understand it. That's just my typing problem haha. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you have created a link but cannot access the file if you do cat.

1. You should have permission to cat original file.
2. File should be on same file-system/partition.

```
-------------------------- 
Example: 
$ cd / 
$ echo "UBUNTU" > orig.txt 
$ cat orig.txt 
UBUNTU 
$ ls -l orig.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root           0 Jul 26 18:28 orig.txt 
$ ln -s orig.txt /pool0/manager/link.txt 
$ cd /pool0/manager/ 
$ cat link.txt
 cat: cannot open link.txt: No such file or directory

--------------------------
```

Comment: Your command created a wrong symbolic link, i.e. you linked `/pool0/manager/orig.txt` to `/pool0/manager/link.txt`. The first file doesn't exist. This has nothing to do with the same file-system limitation that doesn't affect symbolic links anyway.

Comment: file orig.txt lies in / while symlink lies in other partition /pool0/manager/link.txt which i tested.

Comment: As you wrote the command, `orig.txt` is in the same partition, but doesn't exist.

Comment: You should have typed: `ln -s /orig.txt /pool0/manager/link.txt` (notice the absolute path for `/orig.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for your test Nitin! That's just my typing problem... Haha.

Answer (score 0):

Symbolic links contains a text string that is automatically interpreted and followed by the operating system as a path to a target file or directory.

The most relevant use case of symbolic links is restructuring of file system hierarchy, so keeping the compatibility with old tools and standards like POSIX.

Wikipedia has extensive information on [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).