# What does it mean when a symbolic link (symlink) is red in Ubuntu?

Tags: symbolic-link

```
~/temp$ mkdir dir1
~/temp$ mkdir dir2
~/temp$ mkdir dir2/dir21
~/temp$ ln -s dir2/dir21 dir1/ln2dir21
~/temp$ mkdir dir1/ln2dir21/dir3
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘dir1/ln2dir21/dir3’: No such file or directory
```

What does the following command:

```
~/temp$ ln -s dir2/dir21 dir1/ln2dir21
```

create (there are no errors for the `ln` command)? The created link `dir1/ln2dir21` is red and it's type is `lrwxrwxrwx` which seems to be a link. Then why can't create directory through that symbolic link?

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual page?  ie. `man ln` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question about the symlink of the ln command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324930/question-about-the-symlink-of-the-ln-command)

Comment: I'v read them, but there are too much like form 1/2/3/4 so not very carefully...

Comment: `dir1/ln2dir21` symbolic link is relative to `dir1`. The correct command would be `ln -s ../dir2/dir21 dir1/ln2dir21`.

Comment: `man ls` tells me "ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME" ie. TARGET is first so that's the target of the command, LINK_NAME is second which is the link (-s tells it symbolic) created.   SPACES are delimiters, ie. "dir2/dir21" is the TARGET and "dir1/ln2dir21" the LINK_NAME in format path/file  (where file can be the name of a file or a directory (file contains more files; in posix/unix/linux everything is a file in a way)

Comment: Failure without any error message? ln should print an error message "symbol link not created, target not exists, <absolute target path>"

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866313/how-can-i-fix-red-symbolic-link-in-linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dir1/ln2dir21` symbolic link you created is relative to `dir1`.

The correct command would be:

```
ln -s ../dir2/dir21 dir1/ln2dir21
```

As another test, if you go to `dir1` and create `dir2/dir21` you will see that the red indicator will go away:

```
cd dir1
mkdir -p dir2/dir21
ll
```

You will see `ln2dir21 -> dir2/dir21/` in normal color (no red error color).

Answer (score 1):

`~/temp$ mkdir dir1/ln2dir21/dir3` you can't create a directory in a directory that is inexistent use `mkdir -p`

`ln -s dir2/dir21 dir1/ln2dir21` is not working, because you're a) linking to a file not a dirrectory and b) it should be a full path. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9104390

so it should be: `ln -s ~/temp/dir2/dir21/ ./dir1/ln2dir21`

and it should workl...

Comment: I'm linking to a file, not directory.